# Monitor problems. Ghosting?

Tags: display

I just bought a new monitor, the [EG 27" Gaming Monitor QHD 144hz 1ms](https://www.ebuyer.com/838555-eg-27-gaming-monitor-qhd-144hz-1ms-with-amd-freesync-gs27-v2?reevoo_sort_by=score_asc&reevoo_page=2#reevoo_embedded_reviews) and a [5m DisplayPort cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07P6Y6T6H/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1). However, I have some issues. The main problem that I have is that when I scroll on websites, the text leaves behind a green replica of itself (I think that this is called ghosting?) The ghosting is only there for a fraction of a second and it stops when I stop scrolling.
 It almost looks like a drop-shadow effect in Photoshop. 
I've tried changing back to 60hz, disabling Freesync (using gsync on a 1060)
Another one is that the monitor has shown artefacts once and coloured lines, though I may be imagining this. 
Finally, I have never used 144hz as I have always denied it but I can not see any difference at all, I've changed back to 60hz multiple times, but I can't see any difference on desktop or games. 
Anybody have any ideas?
Many thanks.

Comment: If the ghosting is transient, lasting only a fraction of a second, then the issue could be in the display or cable. If the green overlay remains while you leave the PC untouched, it is due to the video idiosyncrasies of the PC or its incompatibility with that display, and has nothing to do with the display *per se*.

Comment: The ghosting is only there for a fraction of a second and it stops when I stop scrolling.

Comment: This [review](https://www.ebuyer.com/gaming/too-good-to-be-true-we-put-the-eg-27-144hz-gaming-monitor-to-the-test/) points that changing the response time to low can solve the ghosting issue. About the refreshing rate take a look at this [page](https://www.howtogeek.com/359691/what-is-a-monitors-refresh-rate-and-how-do-i-change-it/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I've tried changing the response time to low, but I face the same issue and I have already changed the refresh rate but no difference. Do you think that I should RMA the monitor or could it be the cable? Also, I've tried using HDMI, but there's no signal. 
Many thanks.

Comment: HDMI port doesn't support Freesync. The monitor has dual DVI  port, so you can try changing port. Also you didn't mention what graphics card you have. If you've bought the monitor from an online store like Amazon, Best Buy etc. and you can return it, my advice is to go for a Dell Ultrasharp.

Comment: Hi, I'm aware that HDMI doesn't support Freesync, but the monitor should still work. I don't have a DVI cable on hand and I have a gtx 1060 6gb.

Comment: The monitor's HDMI version is 2.0 so make sure you have a cable that supports it. The DVI port is a dual-link DVI-I, this in case you want to get a DVI cable. I would try both ports to see if things go better...